# Javascript - Associative Arrays not working?

Tags: javascript, csv

So I have csv files that basically include lists of students, what school they are in, and what subjects they are taking(ex. chem, spanish, biology, etc). I want to have my program let the user type in a subject area(s) and have the page return the amount of times each subject is being taken.

I then have some javascript that basically takes in some user input from a text field, parse that, and puts it into an array. Then, it imports the csv file and compares the subject columns to what the user inputs, and calculates the amount of time each subject is taking.

My javascript looks like this:

```
var globalArray      = [];
var schoolList       = [];
var splitTextInput   = [];
var count            = 0;
var splitSubjectArea = []; 

function myFunction()
{
    var textInput = document.getElementById('numb').value;
    var needsTrimTextInput = textInput.split(",");            //creating an array to store user input 

    for( var q = 0; q < needsTrimTextInput.length; q++)          //getting rid of whitespace in user input 
    {
        splitTextInput[q] = needsTrimTextInput[q].trim(); 
    }

    for(var j = 0; j< splitTextInput.length; j++)
    {
        var sSubjectArea = {}; 
        sSubjectArea[ splitTextInput[j] ] = 0;         //assigning the value to 0 to store the count of each subject 
    }

    var fileName = document.getElementById("UniversitySelect").value;

    if( fileName.indexOf(".csv") > 0 )
    {
        d3.csv( "./" + document.getElementById("UniversitySelect").value, bob, counting);
    }

    function bob(d){
        return { Area: d.Area };
    }

    function counting(error, rows)
    { 
        globalArray = rows;
        for( var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++ ) //for the row in the CSV file 
        {                        
            for( var k = 0; k < splitTextInput.length; k++ ) // loop to go through the different inputed subject areas
            {            
                if( rows[i].Area.toLowerCase().indexOf( splitTextInput[k].toLowerCase() ) > -1)
                { 
                    count++; //stores the overall count 
                    sSubjectArea[splitTextInput[k]] += 1;  
                    //console.log(sResearchArea[splitTextInput[k]]);
                }       
            }
        } 
        console.log(rows);
        for(r = 0; r < splitTextInput.length; r++)
        {
            console.log( sSubjectArea[ splitTextInput[r] ] );
        }//for
    }//function
}//function
```

I know it partially works, because if I enter in 2 subjects, say Chemistry and Biology, which are taken 3 times each, then the count will be 6. However, I cannot get sSubjectArea to hold the count for each individual subject. What am I doing wrong? When I added the `console.log(sSubjectArea[splitTextInput[k]])` line, the output I get is:

```
    1 
    NaN 
    2 
    3 
    4 
    NaN 
    5 
    6 
    Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, 86 more… ] 
    NaN
    6
```

And I don't really understand why I get those numbers & especially NaN.... can anyone help? I'm really new to javascript, so I might have made some sort of fundamental error in understanding objects, but I can't figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have an associative array type.

Comment: @Pointy Oh. Well, I meant like objects and properties?

Comment: @Pointy (I'm a software engineer on IE's Chakra JS engine) - I disagree. In ECMAScript every `Object` type can be considered a hashtable (with their "properties" as keys). The main gotcha is that you can't use `Number` values as keys (or `Strings` that could be coerced to `Numbers`).

Comment: @ocean800 please reformat your JavasScript add more intermediate variables so we can more easily trace your code, and also please output the result of `splitTextInputp[k]`. Can you make a jsFiddle?

Comment: @Dai well with all due respect, while I agree that any plain object is *like* an associative array, there are important distinctions. First, the namespace isn't completely "clean", since every object has (for example) a "toString" property whether one has been added or not. Second, unlike associative arrays in at least some languages, the cardinality of the map isn't maintained - there's no `.length` available to keep track of how many values there are. Contrast that with the way the ES6 Map class works.

Comment: @Dai I reformatted my code to make it easier to read. And I don't really know how to make a jsfiddle sorry

Comment: @ocean800 I have completed reformatting your code for you. I have gone through your code and seen numerous logic errors, including using out-of-scope variables that will retain their value (such as using `k` at the very bottom). I suggest stepping through your code first before revising your question. Also, use `console.log` for the property names, not just the resultant values.

Comment: @Dai Thanks, and I didn't even notice that error! But I'll try that, thank you!